# Passing object which implements a child interface as its parent interface parameter

Tags: delphi, interface, delphi-xe7

I have a parent interface (`IParent`), a child interface (`IChild`) and an object which implements the child interface.

I'm trying to call a function which accepts an `array of IParent` parameter by passing an array of objects implementing the child interface.

On compiling I get the following error:

> [dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(46): E2010 Incompatible types: 'IParent' and
>   'TForm1'

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs;

type
  IParent = interface
    procedure DoSomething();
  end;

  IChild = interface(IParent)
    procedure DoSomethingElse();
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm, IChild)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  public
    procedure DoSomething();
    procedure DoSomethingElse();
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure CallAllDoSomething(AArray : array of IParent);
var
  i : integer;
begin
  i := 0;
  while(i < Length(AArray)) do
  begin
    AArray[i].DoSomething();
    Inc(i);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Unit1.CallAllDoSomething([Self]);
end;

procedure TForm1.DoSomething();
begin
  ShowMessage('Something');
end;

procedure TForm1.DoSomethingElse();
begin
  ShowMessage('Something else');
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to assign a `TForm1` object *directly* to an `IParent`, you have to include `IParent` in `TForm1`'s declaration:

```pascal
TForm1 = class(TForm, IParent, IChild)
```

This behavior is documented in Embarcadero's DocWiki:

[Implementing Interface References](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Interface_References_(Delphi)#Implementing_Interface_References)

> An interface-type expression cannot reference an object whose class implements a descendent interface, unless the class (or one that it inherits from) explicitly implements the ancestor interface as well.
>
> For example:
>
> ```pascal
> type
>   IAncestor = interface
>   end;
>   IDescendant = interface(IAncestor)
>     procedure P1;
>   end;
>   TSomething = class(TInterfacedObject, IDescendant)
>     procedure P1;
>     procedure P2;
>   end;
>      // ...
> var
>   D: IDescendant;
>   A: IAncestor;
> begin
>   D := TSomething.Create;  // works!
>   A := TSomething.Create;  // error
>   D.P1;  // works!
>   D.P2;  // error
> end;
> ```
>
> In this example, A is declared as a variable of type IAncestor. Because TSomething does not list IAncestor among the interfaces it implements, a TSomething instance cannot be assigned to A. But if you changed TSomething's declaration to:
>
> ```pascal
> TSomething = class(TInterfacedObject, IAncestor, IDescendant)
> // ...
> ```
>
> the first error would become a valid assignment. D is declared as a variable of type IDescendant. While D references an instance of TSomething, you cannot use it to access TSomething's P2 method, since P2 is not a method of IDescendant. But if you changed D's declaration to:
>
> ```pascal
> D: TSomething;
> ```
>
> the second error would become a valid method call.

Alternatively, since `IChild` derives from `IParent`, you can *explicitly* cast the `TForm1` object to `IChild` first, and then let the compiler convert the `IChild` into an `IParent` for you:

```pascal
Unit1.CallAllDoSomething([IChild(Self)]);
```

This behavior is also documented:

[Interface Assignment Compatibility](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Interface_References_(Delphi)#Interface_Assignment_Compatibility)

> Variables of a given class type are assignment-compatible with any interface type implemented by the class. Variables of an interface type are assignment-compatible with any ancestor interface type. The value `nil` can be assigned to any interface-type variable.

Answer (score 4):

You have to add `IParent` to the declaration of `TForm1`, too:

```
 TForm1 = class(TForm, IParent, IChild)
```

Comment: Indeed. Without that listing of _IParent_ the _TForm1.DoSomething_ is in fact the implementation of _IChild.DoSomething_ and not _IParent.Dosomething_.